# React event onKeyDown only works if I press the key inside an input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make an event listener on the Escape key to exit a menu, but it only works when I press the key while being in an input. This is my function:

```
<div onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if(slidingMenu[0] === 'd-block' && e.key === 'Escape') {
            toggleEditMenu()
        }
    }} className={`shadow ${slidingMenu[0]}`}>
```

This div is the parent of the menu I'm trying to close

toggleEditMenu() is just a function that changes the div class to d-none

Comment: The focus has to be within the element for this event to be fired. The best approach is to bind keydown events to `document` itself.

Comment: and how can I do that in React? I mean, I could do that with just vanilla JavaScript, but I'd like to know if there's a way in React to handle that event to the document itself

Answer (score 0):

The focus has to be within the element for this event to be fired. The best approach is to bind keydown events to document itself. You can try something like,

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handlerFunction);
    // return cleanup funtion to remove the handler after use
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', handlerFunction);
    } 
}, []);
```